# How to store HTML/CSS/JS in a database, or basically build unique pages on a per user basis?

Tags: architecture, frontend, backend

We have a scenario where a user can have a certain type of pages that are more or less unique and different from the rest of the application.

These pages are essentially forms for the users to fill up. And these forms can be totally unique for that user only in some cases.

What are some ways to manage these forms pages? These forms and their data needs to be stored in the database as well. Is there a way to package html/css/js somehow in a database and query as required for users, and then build that page for them to use/submit data? Or what other methods/architecture can be used to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could build a simple CMS type application where the structure of each page is stored as a template file, while text/images can be stored in the database under each user's ID branch...making each page unique.

Edit: Not sure if that's what your question was specifically asking. Feel free to be more specific and I'll try my best to help out.

Comment: It has to be within the existing application, which is not exactly like a CMS. I see what you mean though. Can you elaborate on how to store as a template file?